# How to get website id using Order Object in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to get the website id using a Sales/Order object in Magento.

I tried the code below. But it is not working.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
foreach($order as $o){
  //Here i want to get store id and website id 
  echo $o->getStoreName();
  echo $o->getStoreId();
  echo $o->getWebsiteId();

}
```

Store id works as expected. But the website id is reported as `null`.

Please suggest any other way, which works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($o->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId()
```

The above code should get the website id of the store that your order was placed in.

Comment: You can use this code to get the direct website id<?php $website_id = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId(); ?>

Comment: @Patel Dixit No way but the above. Orders haven't directly associated website data

Comment: Using Mage::app()->getWebsite() will get the current website that you are viewing, which I would assume would be the admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

If the store id is coming right then you can try this,

```
$storeId = $o->getStoreId();
$websiteId = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId)->getWebsiteId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try better this:

```
Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId();
```